# Add active class to next sibling

Tags: javascript, css

Could someone help me with this, I am a bit stuck with JavaScript. Every time when someone is clicking on the question, the active class name should be added to the next sibling, but how to get that fixed. Only in plain JavaScript please. Any other frameworks do not count.

```js
document.querySelector(".question").addEventListener("click", function() {
 if(this.classList.contains("active")) {
  this.classList.remove("active");
 } else {
  this.classList.add("active");
 }
});
```

```css
.faq-block .question,
.faq-block .answer {
 border: 1px solid red;
 padding: 10px;
}

.answer {
  display: none;
 }

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq-block">
    <div class="question">How do I cancel my order</div>
    <div class="answer">Answer</div>
</div>

<div class="faq-block">
    <div class="question">I am not getting an internet connection from my second SIM card</div>
    <div class="answer">Answer</div>
</div>

<div class="faq-block">
    <div class="question">My charger does not work and my device would not charge properly</div>
    <div class="answer">Answer</div>
</div>

<div class="faq-block">
    <div class="question">My fingerprint scanner is not working and does not respond when touched</div>
    <div class="answer">Answer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @brk I have changed that already, my bad

Answer (score 1):

Use [**querySelectorAll**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) ,`document.querySelector` will only select first matched element.

```
// get all matched element
var ques = document.querySelectorAll(".question")
// loop over the array to add event to each of the element    
ques.forEach(function(item, index) {
   // creating closure
  (function(i) {
    // adding event listerner to each element
    ques[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      // this refers to the current selected element
      if (this.classList.contains("active")) {
        this.classList.remove("active");
      } else {
        this.classList.add("active");
      }
    });
  }(index)) // passing the index to target element in the array
})
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/La1c1p7f/5/)

Comment: Great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.querySelector(".question").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(this.classList.contains("active")) {
        this.classList.remove("active");
        this.nextSibling.classList.add("active")
    } else {
        this.nextSibling.classList.add("active");
    }
});
```

I don't know why u need to do conditional checking. but to answer your question, you can use nextSibling

Answer (score 0):

A simple adjustment to your CSS will do the trick:

```
.question.active+.answer {
    display: block;
}
```

This will allow you to set the "active" class on the question, and let it reveal the answer.

Alternatively, use `this.parentNode` for the class, and then the CSS becomes:

```
.faq-block.active>.answer {
    display: block;
}
```

This, I would argue, conveys more meaning too.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `document.querySelector(".question")` returns the first element matching selector([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)).

If i understood right you wanted to get `.active` class applied to Answers so here you are:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".question")
        .forEach(element => element.addEventListener("click", function () {
                nextNode = this.nextElementSibling;
                if(!nextNode.classList.contains("active")){
                    nextNode.classList.add("active");
                }
                else{
                  nextNode.classList.remove('active');
                }
            })
        );
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0phkwnb8/)